# Java: Best way to sort if Date is before a Sorted List of Dates using AWS-SDK-S3 Bucket versioning?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm pulling a versioned object from a S3 bucket using the AWS-SDK. My method receives a specific date and I need to check if that object is made between the versioned dates. What's the best way to approach this?

Here is an example of the version + last modified date that I'm pulling from S3 version history:

```
version 11, last modified date: Mon Jul 31 14:00:00 2023" // Current version
version 10, last modified date: Thu Jun 15 13:00:00 2023"
version 9, last modified date: Wed May 31 12:00:00 2023"
version 8, last modified date: Fri May 05 12:00:00 2023"
version 7, last modified date: Thu Mar 30 18:00:00 2023"
version 6, last modified date: Wed Mar 15 13:00:00 2023"
version 5, last modified date: Wed Feb 01 16:00:00 2023"
version 4, last modified date: Tue Nov 29 10:00:00 2022"
version 3, last modified date: Wed Nov 09 10:00:00 2022"
version 2, last modified date: Fri Oct 07 13:00:00 2022"
version 1 last modified date: Tue Aug 09 11:00:00 2022"
version null, last modified date: Tue Jun 28 10:00:00 2022"
```

And here is my Date parameter that is being passed in that needs to correspond to a specific version: `"02/27/2024 16:58:30"`.

If there was only one object that I could compare against that would be no problem, but I'm not sure what's the best way to sort this list is and find which version would best correspond to the field that's passed in.

I'm saving my values that i'm receiving from S3 in a TreeMap (So they come back always sorted by date), the Tree map looks like: `Map<Date, String> treeMap = new TreeMap<>();`

Would the best way to compare each date be comparing them one at a time and if the date is before that date, then keep comparing down the list until it's no longer before and then break out of a loop?

For reference here is the code I have now, which technically works but I feel like it's not performant in the slightest.

```
      Date newestPdfDate = (Date) treeMap.keySet().toArray()[treeMap.size()-1];
      String pdfVersionToReturn = treeMap.get(newestPdfDate);

      for(int i = 0; i < treeMap.size(); i++)
      {
        Date pdfDate = (Date) treeMap.keySet().toArray()[i]; // Key
        String pdfVersion = treeMap.get(pdfDate); // Value

        if(applicationApprovedDate.before(pdfDate)) {
          pdfVersionToReturn = pdfVersion;
          break;
        }
      }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: By the way, never use either `Date` class. Long ago supplanted by the *java.time* classes.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a loop.  `TreeMap` has a [`higherEntry`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html#higherEntry(K)) method which takes care of this:

```
Map.Entry<Date, String> entry =
    treeMap.higherEntry(applicationApprovedDate);

if (entry == null) {
    entry = treeMap.lastEntry();
}

String pdfVersionToReturn = entry.getValue();
return pdfVersionToReturn;
```